# TwilioRestException: HTTP 401 error: Unable to create record : Python

Tags: python, django-rest-framework, twilio, twilio-api

I'm getting an error: `twilio.base.exceptions.TwilioRestException: HTTP 401 error: Unable to create record: Authenticate`.

if anybody could help me then would be much appreciated.

Comment: Deleted screenshot which had confidential information. Auth Tokens and How to Change Them (rotate credentials)
https://support.twilio.com/hc/en-us/articles/223136027-Auth-Tokens-and-How-to-Change-Them

Answer (score 2):

I also faced the same problem while trying their tutorial, what seemed to be the error was that the value of `auth_token`  was given under square brackets as  `['*******************']`. Removing the square brackets and keep it as a string solved it for me.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me as well when I ran out of credits for twilio. Try adding more money into your account to reactivate it.

Comment: Yes! Twilio changed its privacy policy. Before, it was working fine,